# Angular - post a comment to database

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying post a comment from an input form to my database. The comment I am passing in currently logs as undefined. The service doesn't log and I get a 500 server error: user_id violates not null constraint. What am I doing incorrectly?

HTML(updated)

```
<div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl as commentsCtrl">
 <div ng-show="makeComment" class="collapsible-header">
     <input ng-model="comment" type="text" name="comment" id="comment_content" class="col s11 m11 l11" placeholder="Make a comment.">
         <a href="" type="submit" class="col s1 m1 l1 black-text comment" ng-click="commentsCtrl.createComment(comment, userId, postId)"><i class="material-icons">check_circle</i></a>
  </div>
```

Controller - CommentsCtrl(Updated)

```
this.comment = '';

createComment(comment, userId, postId) {
 return this.commentsService.createComment(comment, userId, postId);
 }
}
```

Service - CommentsService(Updated)

```
this.createcomment = $http;
this.commentContent = '';
this.postId;
this.userId;

createComment(comment, userId, postId) {

this.createcomment.post('/comments', { comment: this.commentContent, userId: this.userId, postId: this.postId })
.then((res) => {
  this.comment = res.data;
})
.catch((err) => {
  return err;
});
}
```

Comment: Why do you `JSON.stringify` the POST data? just pass a json object (`this.createcomment.post('/comments', { comment: commentContent, user_id: userId, post_id: postId })` and on the server the params will be available as `comment`, `user_id` and `post_id`)

Comment: Oh, and you need to save a reference to `this` like this: `var self = this;` and in the promise resolve/reject functions, you need to refer to the controller using `self.comment = res.data;`

Comment: Thank you, I have the controller working now. I can log the comment and see it's being passed to the service. However the service only logs: comment undefined undefined. So the userId and postId are not defined. What is the proper way to define them if my service is a constructor object?

Comment: Take a look at the view: `ng-click="commentsCtrl.createComment(comment)"` You don't pass the userId and postId to the function

Comment: Cool, I added the postId and userId to the function but am still returning undefined for those params. Am I passing them correctly? I updated the code above to show my changes.

Comment: do u have team viewer?

Comment: Well, if it's a single post page, then you don't have to pass those parameters (As I wrote on my previous comment). I think what you need to do is to add in your service `var self = this;` (After this line: `this.userId;), and in the service `createComment` function you need to pass: `this.createcomment.post('/comments', { comment: comment, userId: self.userId, postId: self.postId })`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any values for userId or postId:

```
this.commentsService.createComment(comment);
```

They are null.